# how to setup lighttpd for subdirectory mappings?

Tags: installation, lighttpd, subdirectory

For the same host name, I want to do mapping like the following

```
/subdirectory/_different_end_points_.json map to 127.0.0.1:9001

/_different_end_points_.json map to 127.0.0.1:9002
```

How to do that? per documentation, it's required that the else clause has to match on a condition as well, which drives me nuts (as a beginner on regular expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like that:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/subdirectory/_different_end_points_.json" {
  proxy.server = (
    "/" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9001))
  )
}
else $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/_different_end_points_.json" {
  proxy.server = (
    "/" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9002))
  )
}
```

That way, you match each url that **starts** with `/subdirectory/_different_end_points_.jso` or (in the else) `/_different_end_points_.json`.

But be sure that your url realy start with the regex! I mean: h*tp://sample.com/subdirectory/_different_end_points_.json and h*tp://sample.com/_different_end_points_.json